# How to limit results from a query with join and where

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many, left-join, limit

I'm using MySQL.

There are two tables `titles` and `genres`, where the two types of records have a many to many relationship. So there is also a third table called `title_genre_relationships`.

I'd like to select all the titles which have certain genres and do the pagination.

My first thought is:

```
SELECT
  titles.name, genres.name
FROM
  titles
  LEFT JOIN
    title_genre_relationships
    ON titles.id = title_genre_relationships.title_id
  LEFT JOIN
    genres
    ON genres.id = title_genre_relationships.genre_id
WHERE
  genres.name IN ('one', 'two')
ORDER BY titles.name ASC
LIMIT 100, 20;
```

However the limit will return 20 results of the joined result, instead of returning 20 results of the titles.

I've seen many answers using an embedded select and limit query on titles as the left most table in the outer query. That solution doesn't work for me because although it guarantees that the limit is put on titles, but doesn't guarantee that they are the titles which has the required genres.

Also there are some solutions which generates all the title IDs of the ones with expected genres. And then put them in an `in` condition in the outer where section. Here I have a concern about the performance. If the number of the matching titles are huge, is it still efficient?

Is it possible here to put an limit on the returned titles instead of the joined result in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `select  distinct titles.*`

Comment: `genres.name in ('one', 'two')` means _either_.  Did you want _both_?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Cositanto and @Rick James, the comments have inspired me and finally I've come up with a satisfying solution

```sql
-- The outer query is used for adding additional related data to the
-- result set.
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    -- The inner query is used for generating all the IDs of the
    -- titles, which fulfills all the filtering criteria, while
    -- dealing with pagination
    SELECT
      -- DISTINCT for limiting the number of different titles
      DISTINCT(titles.id)
    FROM
      titles
      LEFT JOIN relationships
        ON titles.id = relationships.title_id
      LEFT JOIN genres
        ON genres.id = relationships.genre_id
    WHERE
      genres.name IN ("genre 1", "genre 3")
    -- GROUP BY is required by COUNT
    GROUP BY titles.id
    -- HAVING is required since we need "genre 1" AND "genre 3" instead of OR
    HAVING COUNT(titles.id) = 2
    ORDER BY titles.name ASC
    LIMIT 100, 20
  ) as results
  LEFT JOIN titles
    ON results.id = titles.id
  LEFT JOIN relationships
    ON titles.id = relationships.title_id
  LEFT JOIN genres
    ON genres.id = relationships.genre_id;
```